# Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am getting an error saying that the view is "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate" when I keep my foreach loop in the view. When I take my foreach loop out of the view it works fine. I just started getting this error when I implemented looping over an object before I just looped till a certain number passing in "Dummy Strings" into the ExerciseTableRow view. Not sure how to get around this. Thank you in advance!

```
struct PassedExerciseCard: View {
    var exercise : String
    var sets : [ExerciseSet]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text(exercise).font(.title).padding(.bottom, 5)
            Group{
                HStack{
                    Group{
                        Text("Set")
                        Text("Weight")
                        Text("Reps")
                    }.padding(.horizontal, 30)
                    .offset(x: -15, y: -5)
                    
                }
                VStack{
                    ForEach(sets, id: \.self){ (set : ExerciseSet) in
                        ExerciseTableRow(set: set.set, readOnly: true, setWeight: set.weight, setReps: set.reps)
                    }
                }.padding(.bottom, 5)
            }.offset(x: 20, y: 0)
            
            
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.offWhite)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x:10, y:10)
        .shadow(color: Color.white.opacity(0.7), radius: 10, x:-5, y:-5)
        .padding(.vertical)
    }
}

struct PassedExerciseCard_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var exercise :[ExerciseSet] = []
    
    static var previews: some View {
        PassedExerciseCard(exercise: "Bench", sets: exercise)
    }
}
```

UPDATE

I learned that the error I am having isn't the error at all. The actual error is that the compiler thinks I don't have properties for the ExerciseSet which is an NSManagedObject. I updated the object to have an idea and updated the foreach loop to use the specific ID for each element as the identifier and still no luck.

Updated Code:

```
struct PassedExerciseCard: View {
    var exercise : String
    var sets : [ExerciseSet]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text(exercise).font(.title).padding(.bottom, 5)
            Group{
                HStack{
                    Group{
                        Text("Set")
                        Text("Weight")
                        Text("Reps")
                    }.padding(.horizontal, 30)
                    .offset(x: -15, y: -5)
                    
                }
                VStack{
                    ForEach(sets, id: \.exerciseSetId){ set in
                        ExerciseTableRow(set: set.set, readOnly: true, setWeight: set.weight, setReps: set.reps)
                    }
                }.padding(.bottom, 5)
            }.offset(x: 20, y: 0)
            
            
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.offWhite)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x:10, y:10)
        .shadow(color: Color.white.opacity(0.7), radius: 10, x:-5, y:-5)
        .padding(.vertical)
    }
}
```

NSManagedObject Entity:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension ExerciseSet {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ExerciseSet> {
        return NSFetchRequest<ExerciseSet>(entityName: "ExerciseSet")
    }

    @NSManaged public var reps: Int16
    @NSManaged public var set: Int16
    @NSManaged public var weight: Int16
    @NSManaged public var exerciseSetId: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var origin: Exercise?

}
```

Also Exercise set has a one to one relationship with workout which is:

```
extension Workout {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Workout> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Workout>(entityName: "Workout")
    }

    @NSManaged public var date: String?
    @NSManaged public var muscle: String?
    @NSManaged public var workoutId: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var exercise: NSSet?
    
    public var wrappedDate: String{
        date ?? "Unknown Date"
    }
    
    public var wrappedMuscle: String {
        muscle ?? "Unknown Muscle"
    }
    
    public var exerciseArray: [Exercise] {
        let set = exercise as? Set<Exercise> ?? []
        
        return set.sorted{
            $0.wrappedName < $1.wrappedName
        }
     }

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for exercise
extension Workout {

    @objc(addExerciseObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToExercise(_ value: Exercise)

    @objc(removeExerciseObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromExercise(_ value: Exercise)

    @objc(addExercise:)
    @NSManaged public func addToExercise(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeExercise:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromExercise(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

In the view that calls the PassedExerciseCard (Where the error is being thrown) I pass in the property on the WorkoutEntity : "exerciseArray" into the sets property that I am using in the foreach loop. I believe this is where the error is occurring

Exercise Table Row:

```
struct ExerciseTableRow: View {
    @State public var weight : String = "0"
    @State public var reps : String = "0"
    var set : Int
    var readOnly : Bool
    var setWeight : Int
    var setReps : Int
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack{
            Text(String(set))
                .padding(.trailing, 40)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
            if readOnly == false{
                Group{
                    TextField("0", text: $weight)
                    TextField("0", text: $reps)
                }.textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(width: 50)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
            }
            else{
                Group{
                    Text(String(setWeight))
                    Text(String(setReps))
                }
                .frame(width: 50)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                    .padding(.bottom, 5)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `ExceriseSet`? Why do you believe `\.self` is a valid id here? Is there an ExceriseSet.set that is the correct type to pass to ExerciseTableRow? Simplify, simplify, simplify, and find the smallest block that causes the error. Then the problem will generally make itself known?

Comment: The block of code that causes the error is the ForEach loop. ExerciseSet is an NSManagedObject and when I had my foreach loop set up like:  ForEach(sets, id: \.self){set in
                        ExerciseTableRow(set: set.set, readOnly: true, setWeight: set.weight, setReps: set.reps)
                    }

Comment: It throws an error "Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'reps'" but when I set the foreach loop up like I have in the above code it throws that other exception stated in the title

Comment: `exerciseSetId` is an optional. An Optional isn't an ID type. If you want to iterate over a list, you need to make sure that every element has an ID and they all need to be unique; it can't be optional.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I tried that and it still hasn't worked. I added some more details above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you have a mismatch between data types:

```
extension ExerciseSet {
    ...
    @NSManaged public var reps: Int16
    @NSManaged public var set: Int16
    @NSManaged public var weight: Int16
    ...
}
```

but in the `ExerciseTableRow` they are of type `Int`:

```
var set : Int
var setWeight : Int
var setReps : Int
```

Change them to `Int16` and it will work:

```
var set : Int16
var setWeight : Int16
var setReps : Int16
```